# Automated testing in Titanium (appcelerator)

Tags: tdd, automated-tests, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have developed an app and would like to add automated testing in it. How can I achieve this, there does not seem to be any docs that covers it on the official web site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOASTA’s TouchTest for test automation. This [link](http://www.appcelerator.com/press-releases/appcelerator-and-soasta-partner-test-automation-solution/) might help you.

Comment: You can read everything about Appcelerator Test (via SOASTA) here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Test

Comment: How can you do automated testing if it is dependent on a push notification?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing you could use [tio2](http://npmjs.com/tio2) which runs Mocha tests against your app.